# How to run a Cloud Scheduler job every 5 minutes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, scheduler, google-cloud-scheduler

I currently have `5 * * * *` set as the Frequency of my Cloud Scheduler job. From looking at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules?#defining_the_job_schedule), I expect it to run every 5 minutes; however, I see the results by each hour instead.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 8):

You could use [this place here](https://crontab.guru/) to interactively test your crontab times...

And use

```
*/5 * * * *
```

for `every 5 minutes`, means at minutes 0,5,10,15,...

I also like

```
3-57/5 * * * *
```

for `every 5 minutes starting with minute 3`, meaning at minutes 3, 8, 13, 18,...

Comment: This format is not allowed because if you set it in a cron.yaml and deploy it, it gets you the following error: `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cron jobs only support Groc format for schedule.`

Answer (score 6):

**Fun fact:** If you want to run your job every 5 minutes, write in the schedule field `every 5 minutes`!!

In fact, the schedule format is compliant with the previous [AppEngine CRON format](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref) that uses full text description for CRON scheduling.

But Google has introduced Linux CRON format, because it's more known by everybody and more flexible (and I guess easier to parse!)